# convert from np.datetime64 to float year

Tags: python, python-3.x

from text '2010-09-02 00:00:00'

want to make as float type year like 2010.7xxx

How can I do it?

with Python 3.xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PyAstronomy` which has https://pyastronomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyaslDoc/aslDoc/decimalYear.html#PyAstronomy.pyasl.decimalYear

```
pip install PyAstronomy
```

Then:

```
In [1]: from PyAstronomy import pyasl

In [2]: import datetime as dt

In [3]: d = dt.datetime(2010,9,2,0,0,0)

In [4]: pyasl.decimalYear(d)
Out[4]: 2010.668493150685
```